# Redmine backlogs : could not locate gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine, redmine-plugins

I installed redmine on my server.
Redmine is installed in */usr/share/redmine*.

I try to install redmine backlogs using [the installation guide](http://www.redminebacklogs.net/en/installation.html))
As mentionned in the guide, I execute the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/redmine
bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install
```

It fails with the message: *Could not locate Gemfile*

It looks like the bundle command is waiting for a gemfile in the directory but this file is missing.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

EDIT: Note that I installed Redmine using the Wheezy backports. Maybe we cannot install plugins when Redmine has been installed from the Debian package....

Thank you

Comment: After installng Redmine did you manage to start it and connect to the web page?

Comment: Yes, I managed to connect to the web page.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am running into the same issue...

Comment: No i did not. I gave up and installed a software that does not depend on redmine. I installed icescrum.

Answer (score 0):

That url is for sale now, your best bet is to build it from source from the most currently updated fork from that project which is: https://github.com/ahelten/redmine_backlogs

Try this:

```
cd ~/redmine/plugins
git clone https://github.com/ahelten/redmine_backlogs.git
git checkout feature/v1.0.6_inherit_fields
```

Install libs and gems needed by backlogs

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11'
bundle install
```

Test Your Work

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```

NOTE: this assumes that you have git and whatever other development tools and gems you need installed. If you fail to install a gem, scroll up and read the output, chances are you need to add a package mentioned in the output first (sudo apt-get install foo). If you fail to find a gem you are either building in a directory without a Gemfile or the gem the gem file wants doesn't exist ... search rubygems.org if that happens)